# Border moves text up when hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, border

I am trying to make the border appear n hover but when I hover it moves the text up by the border size width. I know there's a fix for this I just can't remember it. Can anyone help?
P.S. Sorry for the rookie question. Only recently started learning.

```html
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: #eee;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  color: white;
  border: #e1e1e1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

Comment: keep the same size for the border

Comment: That didn't do anything. Initially the size was the same but I tried to play around with it and forgot to edit this code

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to always have a border, except the border is transparent normally and transitions to a visible color on hover. Code example below:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>first</a></li>
    <li><a>second</a></li>
    <li><a>third</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```